# Writing dataframe to hive table using PySpark

Tags: pyspark

This may have been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find an exact solution I was looking for.

I have a dataframe df created using:

```
df=spark.sql('''select distinct Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 from sourceTable''')
```

with the following structure

| col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first_row | row | line |

The target table has the following structure where Col_3, rundate and runtime are partition columns in hive

| col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | rundate | runtime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first_row | row | line |  |  |

Now normally when schema matches, I know I can write the df to hive using

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("Col_3").insertInto("TargetTable", overwrite=True)
```

and set

```
hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true
hive.ecec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict
spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode = dynamic
```

The challenge I am facing is that my source schema is different and moreover, I want to partition by Col_3 and month (instead of daily rundate and runtime).

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Would it be **always different** or **one-time different**? And with different schema and partition, how are you expecting the results?